# How to change schema with Fluent NHibernate AutoMapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent

In my database every table belongs to a schema (Person for example.) I am using Fluent NHibernate with Automapping and my question is how I set the schema I want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [convention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions), specifically an `IClassConvention`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SchemaConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Schema("schemaNameGoesHere");
    }
}
```